Java Selenium - I cannot disable "Save as" pop up download in incognito mode - Selenium 4.25.0
Java Selenium - I cannot disable "Save as" pop up download in incognito mode.
The following code still shows "Save as" pop up.
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDir); 
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 2);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.disable_download_protection", true);
chromePrefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);

ChromeOptions options = New ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");
options.addArguments("disable-features=DownloadUI");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs" chromePrefs);

options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen");

I am using Selenium 4.25.0 and Chrome 129.
Is there any Selenium or Chrome official documentation how to do this properly ? Because everyone in the internet is doing different things, none of them work.

Selenium is an integration tester: it should behave the exact same as a normal browser. Why do you think you need to disable this function? (because you're not testing whether the browser works or not: you know links work, because that's how browsers work, so test whether the link is for the right URL, and if it is, that's your integration test done. You already know that if a user were to click that link, it'd trigger a save dialog.

yes, but it crashes the test because Selenium is not able to click on the pop up because this is system pop up. In normal mode (not incognito) the code works.

Note that a selenium test run uses a clean profile, not your own, so your tests already run in what is effectively incognito mode: there are no cookies or storage etc. carried over from anywhere. What are you doing that makes you think you need to explicitly test in incognito mode?

Why do you trigger the action that opens the save-as popup at all? Is there a link, or is it done by JavaScript?

after clicking the link the pop up "Save as" shows up - I will add that automatic downloading works in non incognito mode. I want incognito because in Chrome browser after 3 hours of test I get error "Not enough memory to open this page"

the only thing you should need is: chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDir);   But be sure to check downloadDir first... if that path isn't valid (dir doesn't exist or have proper permissions) then it will fail to set that.  By default I don't think Chrome prompts at all, so it suggests that there's something wrong with the path or permissions.  So try creating File from downloadDir, and try/catch exceptions.  You can also check permissions and set if necessary.  In catch you can create the dir if it doesn't exist and/or set permissions.
